# How to combine RDS & RDS Read Replica DB Identifiers in Terraform

Tags: terraform, amazon-rds, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a TFVARS file to define my RDS instances. Within each RDS variable, I have a value that reads: read_replica = true or false. If true, terraform will create the RDS instance resource, as well as a read replica resource for the RDS. Now I'm trying to create CW alarms but am not sure how to specify the variables to create CW alarms for the RDS AND the RDS read replicas. Here is what I have so far:

```
locals {
  rds_instances = merge(var.rds_postgress, var.rds_mariadb)
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "rds_cpu" {
  for_each = local.rds_instances

  alarm_name                = replace("${each.key}-cpu-utilization", " ", "")
  comparison_operator       = "GreaterThanThreshold"
  evaluation_periods        = 1
  metric_name               = "CPUUtilization"
  namespace                 = "AWS/RDS"
  period                    = 900
  statistic                 = "Average"
  threshold                 = 80
  alarm_description         = "This metric monitors rds cpu utilization"
  insufficient_data_actions = []

  dimensions = {
    DBInstanceIdentifier = each.key
  }
```

This works but is only creating CW alarms for the RDS's and not the RDS read replicas. Also, the DBInstanceIdentifier for the read replica just adds read replica to the end of the name so it would be: replace("${each.key}-read-replica", " ", "").

The read replicas are created using this logic if helpful:

```
for_each = {
    for key, value in var.rds_postgres : key => value if value.read_replica == true
  }
```

Any suggestions on how to add the read replica db's into the list of variables?

Comment: Are you sure `merge` is the function you need ?  ... have you looked at what you get on `local.rds_instances` ??

Comment: Look at the examples on merge: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/merge#examples I get a feeling that is not what you wanted ... maybe `setunion` is what you need https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/setunion